# android for fingerprint scanner for with eclipse

Tags: android

I don't know if it is possible but I want to make a fingerprint scanner for user to log in to my application, so they don't have to input username and password but only scan his/her finger and than open my app.

Is it possible make it? or should I use a touch screen that good enough to read the individual fingerprint?

I'm currently searching for a good application for fingerprint scanner but I can only find fake app.

Comment: "or should I use a touch screen that good enough to read the individual fingerprint?"
I think I had a joke app for PalmOS that did that. If you find a touchscreen good enough to read a fingerprint, uh, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good idea, UI-wise, for several reasons.

- At the moment, there are very few Android phones with fingerprint scanners on the market: the [Atrix 4G](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_atrix_4g-3708.php), the [HTC One Max](http://www.engadget.com/2013/10/15/htc-one-max-review/), which is not yet out, and something from Korea called a Pantech. The market penetration for these devices is minimal to say the least.
- There's supposedly a [fingerprint scanner SDK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1206033) for Android phones released by Authentec in 2011. Their site is down, however, and for a good reason -- *they were bought by Apple.* Whoops! You can probably grab a sketchy copy of it somewhere, but good luck distributing anything based on it.
- Fingerprint scanning to identify users ("which user is this?") as opposed to authenticating users ("is this user who they say they are?") is notoriously unreliable, especially with phone-based fingerprint scanners.

Just use a username and password, or better yet, use OpenID or Google signon or Twitter auth or something. You'll be happier.

Oh, and in case this wasn't clear: **given 2013 technology, anyone claiming to be able to read a fingerprint from a phone touchscreen is lying**.